# How to print 1 value for a new line from dictionary contains 2 values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print this output :

dictionary key : 
    a:
    b:
    c:

value 1 :  abc, sam, rose, mary, jon

value 2 : 20,30,40,50

My code goes like this :

```
result = {'a':['abc',10], 'b':['sam',20], 'c':['rose',30], 'd':['mary',40], 'e':['jon',50]}

print("Email:",'\n'.join([str(key) for key in result.keys()][0:]),sep='\n')
print('The lists are:', '\n'.join([str(value) for value in result.values()]), sep='\n')
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(result.keys())
for arr in zip(*result.values()):
    print(arr)
```

The `zip` function essentially flips the axis order on your lists. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip

To use more zip to print the quantity "name" as well:

```
names = ["name", "qty"]
for name, arr in zip(names, zip(*result.values())):
  print(name, arr)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried to use the above code. It came out nicely..but i need to print ('name:' sam, rose,..) then print('qty:' 20,30,40) ... i tried to modify the above code into for arr1,arr2 in zip(*result.values()): print("name:",arr1)   print("name:",arr2) .. it came out error code of zip object has no attribute values.

Comment: Hi I managed to solve the above with using the zip concept. Skip the for loop. Instead use c, v =  zip(*result.values())
print('name:', c)
print('qty', v)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the document and the zip concept. it is very useful!

Comment: No problem! You can abuse zip further to do what you want with:
```names = ["name", "qty"];
for name, arr in zip(names, zip(*result.values())):
  print(name, arr)```